# Linking multiple .html files to one .js file

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to create a simple login and sign up page. I have created them separately using atom, and they were saved inside the same folder inside my computer. I added a css file and was able to link it to both fine.

Now comes the problem.

Note: This is just a fun little project which is why I only used localStorage.

I created a .js file inside my website folder.

```
//SIGN UP PAGE
function create(){
  var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
  localStorage.setItem(username, un);
  localStorage.setItem(password, pw);
  window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Desktop/Social_Share/ssprofile.html";
}
//LOGIN PAGE
function login(){
  if(document.getElementById("usernamel") === localStorage.getItem(username)){
    if(document.getElementById("passwordl") === localStorage.getItem(password)){
      window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Desktop/Social_Share/ssprofile.html";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Incorrect Password or username";
    }
  }else{
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Sorry, this account does not exist";
  }
}
```

And made it to add values to the localStorage when create account button is pressed.

```
<script src="ssjavascript.js"></script>
```

This is the exact same code I used for both the html files to connect to the js files, and yet, only one works. No matter what, only one of the html files can connect to the js file. I've copied and pasted multiple times. I've tried different tags. I've tried everything I can think of and this is where I beg the internet myself for answers.

To test If it is working, I created an onclick() function to a button and told it to bring me to a separate page. None of it worked, I checked my spelling about 10 times now as well.

Also, Whenever I test the files I open them in browser, so I don't get any error messages. And I can't test them in atom because it just shows the code in a scroll box on view.

Edit:

```
ssjavascript.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at login (ssjavascript.js:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (sslogin.html:22)
```

This is what I got when clicking the button on the non-working page.

login is referring to the button clicked

ssjavascript.js is referring to the file I used to hold the javascript

sslogin.html is the page file

I don't know if this helps, I've lost track quite a bit.

Full Code:

Sign Up page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Sign Up
        </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="sscss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo">

        </div>
        <div id="logo2">
        </div>
        <div id="usernametxt">
            Username:
        </div><input id="username">
        <div id="passwordtxt">
            Password:
        </div><input id="password"><br><br>
        <div id="security">
            For the sake of security,<br>we suggest creating a unique<BR>password specific for this site.<br>
            You are also limited to 1<br>account, creating a new one<br>will erase previous data.
        </div><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="create()" value="Create Account"><br><br>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Desktop/Social_Share/sslogin.html">Already Have One? Log In</a>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="ssjavascript.js">
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Log in page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Log In
        </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="sscss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo">

        </div>
        <div id="logo2">
        </div>
        <div id="usernametxt">
            Username:
        </div><input id="usernamel">
        <div id="passwordtxt">
            Password:
        </div><input id="passwordl"><br><br><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="submitl" onclick="login()" value="Login"><br><br>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Desktop/Social_Share/sscreateaccount.html">Don't Have an Account? Create One</a>
      <br><br>
      <div id="errormsg">

        </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="ssjavascript.js">
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the javascript file is already up above, and the profile page is just a blank until I actually figure out how to get someone there.

Also, I changed the Javascript to compare the value to localStorage instead of assigning but it seems to still not work as intended.

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions. Even if none of them singularly worked, I still wouldn't have fixed my problem if you guys haven't pushed me to do some more searching.

I found out, that using `""` saved my variables as strings, so I used `''` and it worked exactly how I wanted.

Again, thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: How are you determining that the other HTML files can't connect to the JS file?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error? Use the F12 debugger to see if there are any runtime errors. Are the html files in the same directory as the javascript file?

Comment: Re edit: "None of it worked" isn't a very useful problem description. Look at the console. Are there errors? Look at the network tab: Is the JS file being requested? Is it loading correctly?

Comment: The issue sounds likely to be in one of the html files, but you've omitted to include those in your question which makes it kinda hard to help. Can you consider creating a temporary copy of the folder and reducing both html files to the minimum that still reproduces the issue. In other words you should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `=` is an **assignment**, not a comparison (which is `===` or `==`). You make that mistake **several** times.